# Mcp2515 on i.MX8M

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, can-bus, device-tree, imx8

I have MaaxBoard-Avnet and Mcp2515. I am trying to run mcp2515 with MaaxBoard for spi to CAN.

Mcp2515 worked with MaaxBoard on kernel 4.14 however when I try same configuration for kernel 5.4. mcp2515 can't work. I tried to explain my studies and results below.

I compiled an image using the steps on the https://github.com/Avnet/meta-maaxboard/tree/zeus. I added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " can-utils"` to yocto **local.conf** file for can commands.

**Kernel configuration:**

```
Networking support  --->
<*>   CAN bus subsystem support ---> 
    --- CAN bus subsystem support
    <*>   Raw CAN Protocol (raw access with CAN-ID filtering)
    <*>   Broadcast Manager CAN Protocol (with content filtering)
          CAN Device Drivers  --->
              <*> Virtual Local CAN Interface (vcan)
              <*> Platform CAN drivers with Netlink support
              [*]   CAN bit-timing calculation
              CAN SPI interfaces --->
                     <*> Microchip 251x series SPI CAN Controller
```

**.dts configuration:**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2019 EMBEST
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
 * as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
 * of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 */

/* 40-pin extended GPIO, expanded into SPI, I2C, PWM and other interfaces */

&iomuxc {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_hog>;

    imx8mq-evk {
        pinctrl_hog: hoggrp {
            fsl,pins = <
                /*Default GPIOs*/
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_READY_B_GPIO3_IO16    0x19    /* PIN 7,  GPIO 4  */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_WE_B_GPIO3_IO17       0x19    /* PIN 11, GPIO 17 */
            //  MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_DATA02_GPIO3_IO8      0x19    /* PIN 13,              MCP2515 INT_1 */
            //  MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_DATA03_GPIO3_IO9      0x19    /* PIN 15,              MCP2515 INT_2 */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_RE_B_GPIO3_IO15       0x19    /* PIN 22, GPIO 25 */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_GPIO1_IO03_GPIO1_IO3       0x19    /* PIN 36, GPIO 16      CAN_STB_Maax_Out */
            //  MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_DATA05_GPIO3_IO11     0x19    /* PIN 37,              TRIG_SN65DS183_EN */
                //MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_CE1_B_GPIO3_IO2     0x19    /* PIN 26,              MCP2515 CS_2 */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_CLE_GPIO3_IO5         0x19    /* PIN 29, GPIO 5  */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_DATA04_GPIO3_IO10     0x19    /* PIN 31, GPIO 6  */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_SAI2_TXC_GPIO4_IO25        0x19    /* PIN 12, GPIO 18 */
            //  MX8MQ_IOMUXC_GPIO1_IO15_GPIO1_IO15      0x19    /* PIN 32               WTD_INTERLOCK_Maax */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_SAI2_RXFS_GPIO4_IO21       0x19    /* PIN 35, GPIO 19 */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_SAI2_RXD0_GPIO4_IO23       0x19    /* PIN 38, GPIO 20 */
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_SAI2_TXD0_GPIO4_IO26       0x19    /* PIN 40, GPIO 21 */
            >;
        };

        pinctrl_ecspi1: ecspi1grp {
                fsl,pins = <
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_ECSPI1_SS0_GPIO5_IO9       0x16        // CAN 0 CS
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_CE1_B_GPIO3_IO2       0x16        // CAN 1 CS     GPIO3_IO02
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_ECSPI1_MOSI_ECSPI1_MOSI    0x16
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_ECSPI1_MISO_ECSPI1_MISO    0x16
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_ECSPI1_SCLK_ECSPI1_SCLK    0x1816
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_DATA02_GPIO3_IO8      0x146       //  LVTTL Enabled, Pull-up Enabled, Slew Rate Field :Slow  Interrupt pin CAN0 
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_NAND_DATA03_GPIO3_IO9      0x146       //  LVTTL Enabled, Pull-up Enabled, Slew Rate Field :Slow  Interrupt pin CAN1               
            >;
        };

        pinctrl_i2c2: i2c2grp {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_I2C2_SCL_I2C2_SCL          0x4000007f
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_I2C2_SDA_I2C2_SDA          0x4000007f
            >;
        };

        pinctrl_i2c3: i2c3grp {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_I2C3_SCL_I2C3_SCL          0x4000007f
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_I2C3_SDA_I2C3_SDA          0x4000007f
            >;
        };

        pinctrl_i2c4: i2c4grp {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_I2C4_SCL_I2C4_SCL          0x4000007f
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_I2C4_SDA_I2C4_SDA          0x4000007f
            >;
        };

        pinctrl_uart2: uart2grp {
            fsl,pins = <
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_UART2_RXD_UART2_DCE_RX     0x49
                MX8MQ_IOMUXC_UART2_TXD_UART2_DCE_TX     0x49
            >;
        };

    };
};

&ecspi1{
    fsl,spi-num-chipselects = < 2 >;
    cs-gpios = <&gpio5 9 0 >,<&gpio3 2 0 > ;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ecspi1 >;
    status = "okay";
    #address-cells=<1>;
    #size-cells=<1>;
    can0: spidev@0x00{
        compatible = "microchip,mcp2515";
        clocks = <&osc_8m>;
        interrupt-parent =<&gpio3>;     // GPIO3_IO08   
        interrupts = <8 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
        spi-max-frequency = <8000000>;
        reg = <0>;
    };
    can1: spidev@0x01{
        compatible = "microchip,mcp2515";
        clocks = <&osc_8m>;
        interrupt-parent =<&gpio3>;     // GPIO3_IO09
        interrupts = <9 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_FALLING>;
        spi-max-frequency = <8000000>;
        reg = <1>;
    };  
};

&i2c2 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c2>;
    status = "okay";
};

&i2c3 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c3>;
    status = "okay";
};

&i2c4 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c4>;
    status = "okay";
};

&uart2 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_uart2>;
    assigned-clocks = <&clk IMX8MQ_CLK_UART2>;
    assigned-clock-parents = <&clk IMX8MQ_CLK_25M>;
    status = "okay";
};
```

and also I created new clock node on **imx8mq.dtsi** file. Part of clock node:

```
osc_8m: clock-osc-8m {
        compatible = "fixed-clock";
        #clock-cells = <0>;
        clock-frequency= <8000000>;
        clock-output-names = "osc_8m";
    };
```

**Dmesg outputs:**

`dmesg | grep can` output:

```
[    1.347960] imx-dcss 32e00000.display-controller: ctxld: can't get irq number
[    2.005331] caam-snvs 30370000.caam-snvs: can't get snvs clock
[    2.106505] can: controller area network core (rev 20170425 abi 9)
[    2.117207] can: raw protocol (rev 20170425)
[    2.121489] can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20170425 t)
[    2.127166] can: netlink gateway (rev 20190810) max_hops=1
```

`dmesg | grep mcp` output:

```
[    2.380741] mcp251x spi0.0: CANCTRL 0x0a
[    2.380748] mcp251x spi0.0: Cannot initialize MCP2515. Wrong wiring?
[    2.387132] mcp251x spi0.0: Probe failed, err=19
[    2.402094] mcp251x spi0.1: Cannot initialize MCP2515. Wrong wiring?
[    2.408470] mcp251x spi0.1: Probe failed, err=19
```

`dmesg | grep spi` output:

```
[    1.393667] spi_imx 30820000.spi: dma setup error -19, use pio
[    1.400139] spi_imx 30820000.spi: probed
[    2.380741] mcp251x spi0.0: CANCTRL 0x0a
[    2.380748] mcp251x spi0.0: Cannot initialize MCP2515. Wrong wiring?
[    2.387132] mcp251x spi0.0: Probe failed, err=19
[    2.402094] mcp251x spi0.1: Cannot initialize MCP2515. Wrong wiring?
[    2.408470] mcp251x spi0.1: Probe failed, err=19
```

**Mcp2515 connect to MaaxBoard:**

```
Mcp2515 Output     MaaxBoard Pin Number
INT          ------------->  13
SCK(SCLK)   ------------->   23
SI(MOSI)    ------------->   19
SO(MISO)    ------------->   21
CS(CE0)     ------------->   24
GND         ------------->    6
Vcc(3.3V)   -------------->   1
```

`ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 125000` command output is: `Cannot find device "can0"`

It would be great if you could help me figure out where to look.

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably better off asking this question on Unix&Linux SE or SuperUser, as it is not about programming, but about general computing hardware/software, and therefore off-topic here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you do `make oldconfig` to convert your working config to the new kernel?

Comment: I am not 100% familiar with the CAN support in Linux.  However, it seem that you expect the SPI bus to support a CAN protocol.  You probably have your pinmux right.  It is always instructive to grep the Linux source for the error messages.  I suspect that is it the chipselects.  Look at the bindings in Documentation.  Are these default chip selects of the controller or a GPIO?  Find the code which is printing the "mcp251x" error messages.

Comment: The "Cannot initialize" initialize message means the chip didn't respond to a status read after being sent a reset command. Which unfortunately means just about anything could be wrong. Are you using an off the shelf RPi hat, or something custom? 8mhz SPI sounds a bit optimistic for any test setup. I'd reduce the `spi-max-frequency` to 1mhz.